# Virtual machine very slow after migrating hosts

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, migration

I have just migrated 4 VMs from windows server 2003 R2 to windows server 2008 R3. 3 of the machines are working perfectly, but the fourth is running incredibly slow.

Interactivity is mostly OK, but menu drawing is slow - several seconds to draw, when a program sleeps for about 5 seconds, it actually takes over a minute to wake up, and if I show the task manager performance window, the graph appears to be getting updated about once a minute, rather than every second.

To do the migration, I simply copied the hard drive images, and created new machines with the same configuration as on the source machine. I have checked that they are similar (apart from VB version changes).

Has anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem. In that case the host OS was Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and the guest OS Windows XP. After I upgraded VirtualBox the Win XP virtual machine became VERY slow.

I removed the virtual machine from the VirtualBox menu and re-created it with the same parameters as before, using the exact same hard disk image as before. Problem disappeared and XP became fast (well, as fast as a virtualized XP can be...) again.

Comment: I've tried recreating the VM, but there was no change in the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the settings in that VM for accelerated graphics display?

Comment: I've check these, and they're the same on both systems.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be a bug in VirtualBox 3.2 (see http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7609 and and the related ticket #6842 for details), with our application tickling this bug somehow (though we don't appear to be calling any of the functions that are known to cause the isue).

I have changed back to VirtualBox 3.1 and things are behaving a lot better.